# Working AWS lambda functions and layers with Intellisense in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am deploying a couple of lambdas with layers using cdk and Python3.9.

I have a a folder structure like this below

```
lambda_funcs/_layers/common_layer.py
lambda_funcs/creditor_checks/internal_checks/index.py
lambda_funcs/creditor_checks/external_checks/index.py
```

Both the internal and external checks lambdas use the common code in the layer common_layer.py. In my lambda's index.py when working on VSCode locally, I need to import the layer using an import statement like this

```
from _layers import common_layer as common_
```

However, if I deploy the code like this to AWS the layers are not found and I need to make this correction

```
import common_layer as common_
```

Is there a way to make this work in VSCode so it gives me the intellisense using `import common_layer as common_` alone and not have to use the actual path?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found so far for this is to add your Lambda layer paths as extra paths for Python extension analysis & autocomplete - creating a `.vscode/settings.json` something like the below in the root of your project:

```json
{
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "path/to/your/lambda/layer/source"
  ],
  "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "path/to/your/lambda/layer/source"
  ]
}
```

With this, IntelliSense will be aware of your layer modules like `common_layer.py`... But will think they're available *anywhere* in your project - so try to avoid getting confused if you have very generic-sounding layer module names that seem like they might be relevant elsewhere too!